# Conditional formatting in Excel VBA using the current month and year values in the format conditions

Tags: vba, date, excel, conditional-formatting

In Excel 2013 I'm trying to conditionally format a range of values representing Australian dates (dd.mm.yyyy) with periods as delimiters. The values are all formatted as General.

I've recorded a macro to conditionally format all values containing specific text ".04.2015", but in vba where it has `Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="03.2015",`I'd like to have it use the value of the current month `Month (Now)'` and the current year `Year(Now)`.

Recorded Code:

```
Sheets("MM All").Select

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="03.2015", _
    TextOperator:=xlContains
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Bold = True
    .Italic = False
    .Color = -16711681
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

What I'm trying for (I've just included relevant code from above)

```
Sheets("MM All").Select

Dim MNow As String
Dim NMth As String
Dim YNow As String

MNow = Month(Now)
NMth = Month(Now) + 1
YNow = Year(Now)

Range("E2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select


If (Unsure how to write) Mnow value is single digit
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="0" & "(MNow)" & "." & "(YNow)",
```

I'd also include IFs for when Mnow and Nmth values are double digits, where I just wouldn't have the extra 0 concatenated in the string.

Any help on how I could use the values from Month (Now) and Year (Now) and concatenate them into the Format Conditions string would be much appreciated. I'm new to VBA and trying to feel my way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my attempt. You may try.

```
Public Sub test()

    Dim Mnow As String
    Dim Ynow As String
    Dim Finalstring As String

    Ynow = Year(Now)
    Mnow = Month(Now) + 1

    If Mnow < 10 Then
        Mnow = "0" & Mnow
    Else
        Mnow = Mnow
    End If

    Finalstring = Mnow & "." & Ynow


    Sheets("MM All").Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:=Finalstring, _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = True
        .Italic = False
        .Color = -16711681
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try dateserial

```
CDate(DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now)))
```

and then format as you want with format

```
Format(CDate(DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now))), "yyyy-mm-dd")
Format(CDate(DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now))), "yyyy-mmmm-dd")
Format(CDate(DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now))), "dd.mm.yy")
```

Also pay attention on format function locale sensitivity

or just use

```
myday = Day(Now)
mymonth = Month(Now)
myyear = Year(Now)
vardate = DateValue(myday & "/" & mymonth & "/" & myyear)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those where VBA is not a requirement, a Conditional Formatting formula rule may serve of:

```
=AND(1*MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,2)=MONTH(NOW()),1*RIGHT(A1,4)=YEAR(NOW()))
```